# WCF data service in wcf class library (Have clients talk to database through the service)

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, wcf-data-services

I am creating a simple application where clients need to talk to a server in order to perform simple tasks. The server consists of a database and a WCF service. The clients connect to the service and to the database.

I am using ado.net entity data model to create CRUD operations on the database. **I will like to have the clients create CRUD operations through the service and avoid having the clients connect to the database.**

when I create methods on the service that return entity objects I get an exception. For example I have the method:

```
    public Data.Scheduling[] GetSchedules()
    {
        Data.TCEntities1 entities = new Data.TCEntities1();

        var a = entities.Schedulings.ToArray();

        return a;
    }
```

I don't want to recreate the `Schedulings` class and other entity classes in order to make my methods work. **How will I be able to expose create, read, update and delete operations through my wcf class library service without having the clients connect to the database?**

### Edit

More explanation of my problem in case it is confusing:

In my server application (wcf service) I have basic functionality plus the ado.net entity data classes. Because I have the ado.net entity data classes I am able to extract results from the database very easily such as by doing:

```
    Data.TCEntities1 entities = new Data.TCEntities1();
    var a = entities.Schedulings.ToList(); // schedulings is a table in my database
```

as you can see these line will retrieve all scheduling rows from the table schedulings in the database and It will be essay to work with (I will have a List ). Why do I get an error if I have my wcf service return a `List<Data.Scheduling>` ? I want to prevent the clients from queering the database as they just perform very simple operations (database has only 2 tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF works by exposing contracts. Because you use ADO.NET datamodel, you will get auto generated 'partial' classes. These are not marked with the `DataContract` or `DataMember` which is required by WCF to let them work on the client side. One way or another, you need to copy your partial class into a new class/file and add the attributes so they will show up on the client.

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Entity1
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The classes are marked with the dataContract plus also the serializable attribute... Maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: @TonoNam the methods of the service should also have appropriate attributes like `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract`. Or you need to tell me what kind of exception you are getting.

Comment: The reason why I thought it was not possible is because the client application (wcf client app that start when I start the service) does not support that functionality. I created a client console application and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing question. You create the CRUD WCF calls and client calls the CRUD functions. Service talks to database. Client talks to service. Client doesn't talk with database.

Comment: And this is a confusing answer that would have been better as a comment to the OP.